# Angularjs событие по завершению ввода в поле input

Tags: angularjs

Есть таблица с полями ввода. Нужно чтобы ***по завершению*** ввода в любой из input`ов выполнялось сохранение в БД. Какой data-binding есть в angularjs, с помощью которого это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За событие onBlur, которое срабатывает у input после завершения ввода в angularjs отвечает директива ngBlur (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

А также, `ng-keyup` подписывается на нажатие клавиш. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup

Пример. При потере фокуса или нажатии ввода происходит изменение `value`

```css
    .myFocus {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    .myBlur {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app ng-init="focus=false;blur=false;active=false">
    <input type="text" ng-model="current" ng-class="{ myFocus: focus, myBlur: blur }" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && (value = current);" ng-focus="focus = true; blur = false;" ng-blur="blur = true; focus = false;value = current">
    <p class="myFocus">focus: {{focus}}</p>
    <p class="myBlur">blur: {{blur}}</p>
    <p>value: {{value}}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```